# Alternative to using deprecated save method in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using the following code to save a person object into the database:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setID(1);
        person.setName("name-1");
        person.setAddress("address-1");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Person.class);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(person);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

I see that the **save** method is deprecated. What's the alternative approach that we are supposed to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`save()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object)) is deprecated since Hibernate 6.0. The [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object)) suggests to use [`persist()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#persist(java.lang.Object)) instead.

> **Deprecated.**
>
> *use [persist(Object)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#persist(java.lang.Object))*

Small print: `save()` and `persist()` are similar, but still different. `save()` immediately persist the entity and returns the generated ID. `persist()` just marks the entity for insertion. The ID, depending on the identifier generator, may be generated asynchronously, for example when the session is flushed.

Comment: That is a very incomplete answer. You *MUST NOT* simply replace all occurrences of `save()` with `persist()`, because both methods have a completely different semantics. While `save()` _guarantees_ that a generated key is present in the object after invocation, `persist()` does not. They also have different cascading behavior and who knows what else is different.

It is very likely that just replacing the method calls will break any sophisticated enough application.

Therefore every replacement needs a careful investigation for the consequences and further accompanying changes.

Comment: @UniversE That's a valuable addition. Thanks for sharing! Please feel free to update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

save() was never part of JPA. Since hibernate came before JPA they continued with it and now deprecated and will be removed in the future.
persist(): Persist methods are used to save newly created entities 
merge(): should be used to update detached entity object.
update(): It forces the transition of Entity obj from detached to persistent state. It doesn't make unnecessary SELECT calls unlike merge()
Note: INSERT statements will occur only upon committing the transaction, or flushing or closing the session.

Comment: INSERT statement can also happen immediately if IdentityGenerator requires it. E.g. in case of auto-generated IDs with Identity strategy. Not sure about persist() though.